# Primefaces how add ajax handler to a DynaForm field

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using Primefaces 6.1 and PF Extensions 6.1.
I have DynaForm with some fields and among them I have a select field which I would like to bind an AJAX event handler to (only to this specific one and not for all select fields).

```
DynaFormControl control = row.addControl(mySelectField, "select");
```

Do you think is this possible ? If yes, how?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think dynaform has that flexibility but I might be wrong...